# Good way of creating loops

Tags: haskell

Haskell does not have loops like many other languages. I understand the reasoning behind it and some of the different approaches used to solve problems without them. However, when a loop structure is necessary, I am not sure if the way I'm creating the loop is correct/good.

For example (trivial function):

```
dumdum = do
         putStrLn "Enter something"
         num <- getLine
         putStrLn $ "You entered: " ++ num
         dumdum
```

This works fine, but is there a potential problem in the code?

A different example:

```
a = do 
    putStrLn "1"
    putStrLn "2"
    a
```

If implemented in an imperative language like Python, it would look like:

```python
def a():
     print ("1")
     print ("2")
     a()
```

This eventually causes a maximum recursion depth error. This does not seem to be the case in Haskell, but I'm not sure if it might cause potential problems.

I know there are other options for creating loops such as `Control.Monad.LoopWhile` and `Control.Monad.forever` -- should I be using those instead? (I am still very new to Haskell and do not understand monads yet.)

Comment: You should google for "tail call optimization".

Comment: `a = mapM print [1..2] >> a`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For general iteration, having a recursive function call itself is definitely the way to go. If your calls are in [tail position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), they don't use any extra stack space and behave more like `goto`<sup>1</sup>. For example, here is a function to sum the first n integers using constant stack space<sup>2</sup>:

```
sum :: Int -> Int
sum n = sum' 0 n

sum' !s 0 = s
sum' !s n = sum' (s+n) (n-1)
```

It is roughly equivalent to the following pseudocode:

```
function sum(N)

    var s, n = 0, N
    loop: 
       if n == 0 then
           return s
       else
           s,n = (s+n, n-1)
           goto loop
```

Notice how in the Haskell version we used function parameters for the sum accumulator instead of a mutable variable. This is very common pattern for tail-recursive code.

So far, general recursion with tail-call-optimization should give you all the looping power of gotos. The only problem is that manual recursion (kind of like gotos, but a little better) is relatively unstructured and we often need to carefully read code that uses it to see what is going on. Just like how imperative languages have looping mechanisms (for, while, etc) to describe most common iteration patterns, in Haskell we can use higher order functions to do a similar job. For example, many of the list processing functions like `map` or `foldl'`<sup>3</sup> are analogous to straightforward for-loops in pure code and when dealing with monadic code there are functions in Control.Monad or in the [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package that you can use. In the end, its a matter of style but I would err towards using the higher order looping functions.

---

<sup>1</sup> You might want to check out ["Lambda the ultimate GOTO"](http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html), a classical article about how tail recursion can be as efficient as traditional iteration. Additionally, since Haskell is a lazy languages, there are also some situations where recursion at non-tail positions can still run in O(1) space (search for "Tail recursion modulo cons")

<sup>2</sup> Those exclamation marks are there to make the accumulator parameter be eagerly evaluated, so the addition happens at the same time as the recursive call (Haskell is lazy by default). You can omit the "!"s if you want but then you run the risk of running into a [space leak](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27).

<sup>3</sup> Always use `foldl'` instead of `foldl`, due to the previously mentioned space leak issue.

Answer (score 6):

> I know there are other options for creating loops such as `Control.Monad.LoopWhile` and `Control.Monad.forever` -- should I be using those instead? (I am still very new to Haskell and do not understand monads yet.)

Yes, you should. You'll find that in "real" Haskell code, explicit recursion (i.e. calling your function in your function) is actually pretty rare. Sometimes, people do it because it's the most readable solution, but often, using things such as `forever` is much better.

In fact, saying that Haskell doesn't have loops is only a half-truth. It's correct that no loops are built into the language. However, in the standard libraries there are more kinds of loops than you'll ever find in an imperative language. In a language such as Python, you have "the `for` loop" which you use whenever you need to iterate through something. In Haskell, you have

- `map`, `fold`, `any`, `all`, `scan`, `mapAccum`, `unfold`, `find`, `filter` (Data.List)
- `mapM`, `forM`, `forever` (Control.Monad)
- `traverse`, `for` (Data.Traversable)
- `foldMap`, `asum`, `concatMap` (Data.Foldable)

and many, many others!

Each of these loops are tailored for (and sometimes optimised for) a specific use case.

When writing Haskell code, we make heavy use of these, because they allow us to reason more intelligently about our code and data. When you see someone use a `for` loop in Python, you have to read and understand the loop to know what it does. When you see someone use a `map` loop in Haskell, you know without reading what it does that it *will not* add any elements to the list – because we have the "Functor laws" which are just rules that say any `map` function must work this or that way!

---

Back to your example, we can first define an `askNum` "function" (it's technically not a function but an IO value... we can pretend it is a function for the time being) which asks the user to enter something just once, and displays it back to them. When you want your program to keep asking forever, you just give that "function" as an argument to the `forever` loop and the `forever` loop will keep asking forever!

The entire thing might look like:

```
askNum = do
         putStrLn "Enter something"
         num <- getLine
         putStrLn "You entered: " ++ num

dumdum = forever askNum
```

Then a more experienced programmer would probably get rid of the `askNum` "function" in this case, and turn the entire thing into

```
dumdum = forever $ do
           putStrLn "Enter something"
           num <- getLine
           putStrLn "You entered: " ++ num
```